# Gradient descent for a quantum-classical hybrid neural network

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, pennylane

I am working on implementing a quantum-classical hybrid neural network in qiskit where input data is encoded on a quantum circuit (with say 3 qubits) using a `ZZFeatureMap`, then we have parameterized quantum circuits given by `TwoLocal` gates. Then the measurement is performed on the quantum circuit. The output state of the measurement from the quantum circuit goes to a classical neural network in the form of a bitstring (If the measured state is |001>, then the neural network has an input size of 3 and each node value is given by 0,0,1). After a few layers, we receive the output of the feedforward network and a loss is calculated. (Say mean-square error).

My question is: How do I backpropagate through the quantum circuit? Using `Pytorch`, backprop through the classical neural network is trivial but not the quantum circuit. Is the only way to perform gradient descent through the quantum circuit by applying `parameter-shift` rule to the quantum circuit, keeping all classical parameters constant? I have tried the `TorchConnector` module in qiskit but that directly calculates expectation values of the quantum circuit which is not what I am looking for. [This](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-machine-learning/machine-learning-qiskit-pytorch.html) tutorial on hybrid-quantum-classical neural networks in qiskit might be a solution but again, I cannot think of a way to initialize weights of the parameterized unitaries as asked in [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26641/train-a-quantum-circuit-whose-parameters-are-not-the-input-qiskit-pytorch) question.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I understand it is tricky to do HNN with qiskit because of the lack of examples and explanations in the qiskit textbook. I recommend applying `CircuitQNN` will be more flexible for HNN.
This might help you:

1. https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/01_neural_networks.html#4.1-Output:-sparse-integer-probabilities
2. https://qiita.com/DeepRecommend/items/7a28f2e96ef165a0ed1d#dense-parity-probabilities

Comment: Hi! I'm going through both the tutorials you recommended. I will go through the details of `CircuitQNN` and update if it solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Ananth_Rao accept the answer if the problem been solved will help a lot, thank you. Welcome to ask more questions. Two local is like a quick apply for neurons, because it pre-set most of the things.

Comment: *two layer(not two local)

Comment: @Ananth_Rao for the torchConnector and CircuitQNN, look at this https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/05_torch_connector.html#B.-Classification-with-PyTorch-and-CircuitQNN

Comment: Can you help me understand what the output of the CircuitQNN correspond to (particularly the one with dense probabilities)? How are we constructing sparse probability outputs? I have asked the question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27101/how-does-circuitqnn-in-qiskit-machine-learning-calculate-output-probabiltiies). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pennylane also provides PyTorch/TensorFlow plug-ins which enable back-propagation based optimizers. For instance, for PyTorch you can use [TorchLayer](https://pennylane.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code/api/pennylane.qnn.TorchLayer.html). [This](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_quanvolution.html) might also be relevant for the Hybrid-Neural Network case, since you have both quantum and classical parameters.

Also, [SPSA](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/spsa.html) is another method that you can use, which does not rely on back-propagation, and is significantly faster than parameter-shift, as it creates a perturbation vector to shift all the parameters at once by random scales, so it only requires 2 circuit evaluations, whereas parameter-shift requires exponential number of executions w.r.t the number of parameters. I do not think you even have to "freeze" the classical parameters, and you can include both the parameters for the quantum gates and the classical processing units.

Last but not least, you can also prefer a "[transfer learning](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_quantum_transfer_learning.html)" based approach, depending on the task you want to solve.